# AttributeError: 's3.ObjectSummary' object has no attribute 'download_file'

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook, parquet

I am working with python in jupyter notebook.
I am trying to download all of the files from an aws s3 bucket into my current jupyter directory. I am doing the following code:

```
bucketname = 'my-bucket'
bucket = response.Bucket(bucketname)
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
   key = obj.key
   body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
   obj.download_file('file'+str(count))
   print(obj)
```

but I am getting the error AttributeError: 's3.ObjectSummary' object has no attribute 'download_file'. If I could somehow save them as jsons rather than the parquets they are in now, that would be great, but saving them as is would also work. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try `obj.Object().download_file('file'+str(count))`